# vxWorks-6.9 Wind River 3.3.6 error message make.exe subdirs_all Error 2

Tags: makefile, build, vxworks

I am using Wind River Workbench Version 3.3.6.3 20180920-2158 to build a project, getting the following error message:

C:\WindRiver336\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin\make.exe: *** [subdirs_all] Error 2

Need help to understand the issue, and what to do next.

Searched internet, but did not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above error message is a result of midl.exe not found. Include C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\x64 in the environment path will fix the issue.